# Is Prince the best way to create PDFs in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, princexml

After several Google searches, it appears that the way to create PDFs in Rails from HTML and CSS (versus a new markup language) is to use Prince.

With licensing at $3800 for my non-big-commercial app, I'm wondering if this is, in fact, consensus or people have an alternative they can share the whats and hows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may check out [prawn](http://wiki.github.com/sandal/prawn/) too. Tutorial can be found on [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn).

Comment: I use prawn and I'm happy with it :)

Comment: Yep, and most barcode generating libraries work with prawn too

Answer (score 4):

This may fit the bill: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

We tried tow solutions:

1. using latex generate pdf, there is ruby gem code [rtex](http://rtex.rubyforge.org)
2. using java library [iText](http://www.itextpdf.org/), use it you may need [rjb](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/) which allow you using java lib directly in ruby code, just like jruby, but you don't need build all you application on jruby.

Answer (score 0):

I create tons of different PDF files on the fly from various data sources using Rails, including finest layout. I create need to create them for presenting products to customers.

After having tried all the tools mentioned above, Prince is the best tool for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Prince's rendering quality & CSS support (better than some browsers) is its main selling point. If you're only generating documents with simple layouts, stick with Prawn.